# Cannot find watchOS in AppStore connect after submitting with iOS app

Tags: build, app-store-connect, submit, watchos

I have those targets in Xcode.
I want to upload the iOS app together with the watchOS App.
I select my iOS app Runny and successfuly upload it.

[image]

The problem is, I cannot see the app in the AppStore Connect Console.

PS: I know it is "Waiting for Review", but I got the same problem before sending the iOS app to Review.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The watchOS app wasn't included in the iOS binary.
I had to to hit "+" add new "Copy file phase" and double click to rename it to "Embed Watch Content".
Then, I just had to select my watchOS binary.
Worked like a charm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must add an App Store Icon for the Apple Watch specifically, as well as a few screenshots.

[watchOS Release Guide](https://developer.apple.com/watchos/submit/)

[Screenshot Requirements](https://appradar.com/blog/ios-app-screenshot-sizes-and-guidelines-for-the-apple-app-store#macos-tvos-and-watchos-app-screenshots-sizes)

Comment: Please see my answer for the solution.